# удаление нескольких записей, не вошедших в синхронизацию

Tags: php, mysql

Есть некая таблица `products`.

В эту таблицу выгружаются товары из другого места. Выгрузка происходит путем парсинга `xml` файла и последующих `insert`/`update`.

Так вот вопрос: в прошлый раз выгрузилось `10000` товаров, а сегодня менеджер удалил `40` товаров и уже выгрузилось `9960`. Как удалить из таблицы `products` эти `40` товаров?

Вариант с выбором 10000 айдишников в массив и постепенном удалении из массива очередного айдишника как-то не впечатляет, может есть что-то лучше?

Comment: У товаров ведь есть какие-нибудь идентификаторы? Артикулы? И почему при удалении товаров менеджером они не удаляются сразу из products?

Comment: @EatMyDust товары удаляются в одно время, а выгрузка происходит в другое время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте еще одно поле в таблицу `products` и пишите в него id выгрузки при обновлении, например дату обновления выгрузки или md5 хэш файла-источника. По завершении обновления выполните `delete from products where transaction_key != 'ключ текущего обновления'`

Comment: Ага, хорошее решение.

Answer (score 0):

Если выгрузка происходит с частотой раз в сутки можно просто делать темповую таблицу `products_uploading` далее загружать всю выгрузку туда, а по завершению `products` в `products_uploading` а `products_uploading` в `products` при следующей выгрузки делаем сначала `truncate` таблицы `products_uploading`.

Плюсы такого варианта:

> 1. Прямолинейная логика просто подменяеться таблица
> 2. Вы не ошибётесь при генерации ключа, и не получите ситуацию когда удалены лишние продукты.
> 3. Можно делать бэкапы при перезаписи таблицы `products` при записанном ключе как выше в ответе, после наката бэкапа и отработки
>      алгоритма удалите лишнее.

Минусы:

> 1. Незначительные потери скорости ( но если скрипт по крону выполняеться она и ненужна )

Comment: Ну и потеряем прежние идентификаторы товаров, к которым идет какая-то привязка. Это точно не подойдет для такого случая.

Comment: @lampa Странная у вас архитектура, которая завязана на id товара...

Comment: чем странная? У товара могут быть аксессуары, товары могут в акциях участвовать и прочее.

Comment: @lampa Так аксесуары, акции и прочее грамотнее хранить в сущности товаров. Тогда пересоздал сущность и остались акции, не акции и прочие атрибуты товара.

Comment: так может и проще, но кто будет движок переписывать?